# Change value in STATUS_2 field if M value occurs in STATUS column for a PRODUCT ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following problem. Imagine this is my table:

```
PRODUCT_ID  STATUS  STATUS_2
A1          N       N
A1          M       M
A1          M       M
A1          N       N
A2          N       [NULL]
A2          N       [NULL]
```

If `STATUS` field has a value `M` in any of the rows for a given `PRODUCT_ID`, then `STATUS_2`should be `M` for all of the rows for that `PRODUCT_ID`. For cases where `STATUS` is only `N` (no occurrences) of `M` in `STATUS` then `STATUS_2` should be only `N`.

The desired output when I run the query should be:

```
PRODUCT_ID  STATUS  STATUS_2
A1          N       M
A1          M       M
A1          M       M
A1          N       M
A2          N       N
A2          N       N
```

The tricky part for me is looking at all the entries or rows for for a given `PRODUCT_ID` - in case of `A1` there are four rows - and then populating the `STATUS_2` with the right value.

Can someone please help with a query which will output the table with the correct values for `STATUS_2` as per the output desired above?

Please note `STATUS_2` is a derived column that is not in the original table.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the window function `count()` to calculate number of records with status `M` per Product :

```
select PRODUCT_ID, STATUS, IIF(count_M > 0, 'M', 'N') as STATUS_2
from (
  select PRODUCT_ID, STATUS, count(case when STATUS = 'M' then 1 end) over (partition by PRODUCT_ID) as count_M
  from mytable
) as s
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/plf7eQ9m)

Answer (score 1):

you can use an outer apply for this

```
select p.product_id,
       p.status,
       isnull(t.status, 'N') as status_2
from   product p
  outer apply ( select top 1
                       p2.status
                from   product p2
                where  p2.product_id = p.product_id
                and    p2.status = 'M'
              ) t
```

this results in

| product_id | status | status_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | N | M |
| A1 | M | M |
| A1 | M | M |
| A1 | N | M |
| A2 | N | N |
| A2 | N | N |

See also [this dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5QfPMSkQ)

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clear if you want to update the values in the table or just as a select result.

For an update, you can do something like this:

```
UPDATE T
SET STATUS_2 = IIF(HasM > 0, 'M', 'N')
FROM TableName AS T
JOIN (
    SELECT PRODUCT_ID, SUM(IIF(STATUS = 'M', 1, 0)) As HasM
    FROM TableName
    GROUP BY PRODUCT_ID
) AS C 
    ON T.PRODUCT_ID = C.PRODUCT_ID;
```